# Temporary Teleworking (1 month) Abroad While Employed by US employer

Tags: united-kingdom, us-citizens, working, ukraine

I'm trying to get a handle on what the situation is on remote teleworking for short periods of time (one month or less). I am an American citizen employed by a U.S. employer but work fully remotely. I would like to take short trips to Ukraine and the UK for leisure purposes and would like to telework during those times so I don't have to take vacation. I do not have citizenship in either of those countries.

I do need to record my time to my employer and share the jurisdiction I am working from. If the only option is to just come in on a tourist visa or leave to enter and work on the side illegally, could my employer be held liable in some way?

Thanks very much for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Your employer is not doing anything wrong in this scenario. Your employer is not the one in the foreign country - they are a US entity operating in the US.

But it is quite possible that you might be breaking a local law - some countries have strict laws about working in the country, even if it's working remotely for a foreign company. Where I live in Thailand it is technically illegal, even though the law is rarely enforced (usually only when someone is reported - hint: don't go bragging to people that that's what you are doing while you are there).

Find out from the embassies of the countries where you will visit, whether or not it is OK to work there remotely for a foreign company. It would be even better if you can get them to say it's OK in writing.

Comment: There are several posts on this site establishing that this is not permitted in the UK.  I don't know about Ukraine.  The only country I know where it is explicitly permitted is Canada.